# DynamoDB Sink for AWS Data Analytics (Flink)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, apache-flink

How can DynamoDB be used as a sink to an AWS Data Analytics Application (Flink)?

I'm not finding examples or an existing DynamoDB Sink implementation class.

Comment: I have found two independent implementations on Github:

https://github.com/fabricalab/streaming-flink-dynamodb-connector

https://github.com/klarna-incubator/flink-connector-dynamodb

Is there an official solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dynamo DB Sink connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/dynamodb/) is now available, and details available in official documentation as well.

A sample application using a custom `ElementConverter` can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-aws/blob/main/flink-connector-dynamodb/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/connector/dynamodb/sink/examples/SinkIntoDynamoDb.java). A sample application using the `DynamoDbBeanElementConverter` can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-aws/blob/main/flink-connector-dynamodb/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/connector/dynamodb/sink/examples/SinkDynamoDbBeanIntoDynamoDb.java).

Answer (score 1):

There is no official DynamoDB connector for Flink.

However, there are various third party ones such as

https://github.com/klarna-incubator/flink-connector-dynamodb

Or

https://github.com/fabricalab/streaming-flink-dynamodb-connector

I would strongly suggest that you test any third party connectors to ensure they are production ready and suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Flink community is working on it. This is the related [PR](https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-mongodb/pull/1).

Comment: The link shared is for mongo db connector and not for the dynamo db